# Starting java application

Tags: java, jdk1.7

What is the difference between starting java process by:

```
java -jar application.war
```

and

```
java -classpath application.war org.example.Main
```

Problem is that I'm starting Spring Boot Application with -jar argument, process starts normally, but in eclipse application starts with exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.istack.localization.Localizable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you launch your app with

```
java -jar application.war
```

It will read your `MANIFEST.MF` and pick up your classpath from there, including presumably your missing `com.sun.istack.localization.Localizable`.

When you specify the classpath as the `war`, it finds your `Main` class but does not include the values from the MANIFEST.MF.